# Gitolite Test Fails

Tags: gitolite

So, I'm trying to restore a gitolite installation (along with all repositories) from TimeMachine onto my new iMac (Mac OSX 10.13.4). It's been failing, so I thought I'd try testing gitolite.

I ran the [Trying out gitolite safely](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/install/#trying-out-gitolite-safely) on my machine, that that fails too. Below are the test results, that I don't know what to make of and where to look. Any help is appreciated:

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/basic.t                     (Wstat: 0 Tests: 217 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
t/info-json.t                 (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 1
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/reference.t                 (Wstat: 0 Tests: 16 Failed: 7)
  Failed tests:  10-16
t/ssh-authkeys.t              (Wstat: 0 Tests: 49 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  38, 42
t/ssh-basic.t                 (Wstat: 0 Tests: 26 Failed: 10)
  Failed tests:  15-23, 25
t/vrefs-1.t                   (Wstat: 0 Tests: 88 Failed: 23)
  Failed tests:  43-47, 49, 56-60, 62, 69-73, 79-82, 87-88
t/vrefs-2.t                   (Wstat: 0 Tests: 72 Failed: 8)
  Failed tests:  56-60, 64, 66, 68
t/writable.t                  (Wstat: 0 Tests: 66 Failed: 5)
  Failed tests:  60, 62-63, 65-66
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you could make a fresh install, and then restore your bare repos that were in the folder `repositories/`, including the `gitolite-admin.git/` one (which includes all the configurations)

See "[bringing existing repos into gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/basic-admin/#appendix-1-bringing-existing-repos-into-gitolite)": run, after restoring those repos in your new gitolite instance, `gitolite setup`.

Comment: I was at my wit's end. I tried everything, including your recommendations. Basically, on the new machine, I did not want to restore my old user (which would have lots of old junk). I wanted to selectively copy only stuff I needed. I couldn't get that to happen. Gitolite was not liking it. I'm neither a command line nor ssh expert. In the end, I just ended up restoring both the gitolite hosting and workstation user. I'm not happy, but things are working. Thanks for taking the time.